# In Javascript, what does num = +thenum || false mean?

Tags: javascript

I was self learning JavaScript by reading a book. I can't understand one of the code

```
var thenum = document.getElementById("sr_num").value;
thenum = +thenum || false
```

The last line is never explain throughout the book. I could't understand what is this about. Anyone could explain this to me will greatly appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: There are two different expressions, break it down: let y = `+x`, then `y || false`. What does each expression do?

Comment: It converts the value to a number,  that is what the + is doing, afterwards it checks if the boolean  value of that number is thruthy and if yes, that number is used. All in all, it is meant to be a typesafe string to number conversion,  but "0" will return false...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
thenum = +thenum || false
```

is to make sure that `thenum` is really a valid number. If it is not, then `thenum` will be assigned `false`.

The `+thenum` would try to convert the string value in `thenum` (`document.getElementById("sr_num").value` would give a string value) to a number. If it fails, it would return `NaN`, which is considered as falsy. You can confirm that like this

```
console.log(+"All hail lelouch");
// NaN
```

So, if `thenum` is not a valid number, then the expression becomes

```
thenum = NaN || false
```

Since `NaN` is falsy, the `false` will be assigned in `thenum`.

**Note:** The only valid numeric input for which this expression won't work is `0`. Because when the input is `"0"`, the expression becomes

```
thenum = +"0" || false
       = 0 || false
```

So, `thenum` will still be assigned `false`.

Comment: This code also incorrectly results in `false` for 0. I do not recommend using this idiom, as constructed.

Comment: I'd recommend providing a more valid alternative such as this:
``thenum = (isNaN(+thenum) ? false : +thenum);``

Comment: @PatrickRoberts What's wrong with just using 2 lines? Then you don't have to convert it twice, and you might as well use `parseInt` instead of the silly `+thenum` trick; because the meaning of that is actually, you know, obvious enough that even my grandma can *guess* what *that* means.

Comment: Okay, then how about ``thenum = (isNaN(thenum = parseInt(thenum, 10)) ? false : thenum);``? One conversion, one line, and uses ``parseInt``. This question isn't about readability, it's about the intention of the line, and I was simply suggesting a more valid alternative to what the original code was intended for.

Comment: I would just use `parseInt(str, 10)` (or `parseFloat`) and treat NaN separately or coerece to 0 (not false), depending on intent.

Comment: @user2864740 I would not assume that the code returning `false` for 0 is an error - this may be intentional. It validates whether the input is numerical and positive.

Comment: @Stuart Code returning a polymorphic type is suspect, especially when it is called "the number". `false` is not a number.

Comment: @user2864740 that's a different issue, but I agree. A function `isPositiveNumber` returning `true` or `false` might be better.

Comment: @Stuart Then it should return true or false, not n (n != a false number) or false.

Comment: @Stuart Not to mention negative numbers are also truthy. This is not a positive number validator, 0 is the only falsy number in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLInputElement.value` returns a string. `+thenum` is called the Unary plus operator and converts any value to a `Number` or `NaN`. Since `NaN` is falsy, the OR (`||`) operator would evaluate the second half of the expression, assigning `false` to `thenum`. Another exception is if `+thenum` happens to return 0, the only falsy number. This would assign `false` to `thenum` as well, though this does not appear to be intentional behavior. Aside from these two exceptions, since all other numbers are truthy, the second half of the OR expression will not be evaluated, and the number would be assigned to `thenum`. The following snippets will demonstrate what is going on.

Equivalent behavior:

```
if(+thenum) {
    thenum = +thenum;
else {
    thenum = false;
}
```

(Probably) intended behavior:

```
if(isNaN(+thenum)) {
    thenum = false;
} else {
    thenum = +thenum;
}
```

Shorthand of the above (probably) intended behavior:

```
thenum = (isNaN(thenum = +thenum) ? false : thenum);
```

Hope this helps clarify things.